# Drawing graph with flot, data type not accepted

Tags: php, jquery, graph, flot

I'm trying to draw a graph using flot but it insists not drawing it. The plot will be time vs. value so according to that, Date objects are converted to integer timestamps and mapped with values. Here is PHP code:

```
$row_temp_data=array();
$row_time_data=array();
foreach($restfulData['rows'] as $row){
    array_push($row_time_data, strtotime($row['c']['0']['v'])*1000);
    array_push($row_temp_data, $row['c']['1']['v']);                
} 

$return_array = array_map("self::functionMakePair", $row_time_data, $row_temp_data);
// following render is for testing
$this->render('index', array('return_array'=>json_encode($return_array)));
```

and function to create the pair is:

```
function functionMakePair($pair_1, $pair_2)
{
    return (array($pair_1 => $pair_2));
}
```

This code gives me the following example data structure on the client side, which is $return_array after json_encode:

```
[{"1375937439000":29},{"1375937472000":29},{"1375937506000":29},{"1375937539000":29},{"1375937573000":29}]
```

Corresponding jquery snippet is also here (nothing to suspect here though):

```
$(function () {
    //jQuery Flot Chart     

    var plot = $.plot($("#statsChart"),
        [ { data: <?php echo $return_array?>, label: "Temperature" }], {
            series: {
                lines: { show: true,
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        fill: true, 
                        fillColor: { colors: [ { opacity: 0.1 }, { opacity: 0.13 } ] }
                     },
                points: { show: true, 
                         lineWidth: 2,
                         radius: 3
                     },
                shadowSize: 0,
                stack: true
            },
            grid: { hoverable: true, 
                   clickable: true, 
                   tickColor: "#f9f9f9",
                   borderWidth: 0
                },
            legend: {
                    // show: false
                    labelBoxBorderColor: "#fff"
                },  
            colors: ["#a7b5c5", "#30a0eb"],
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                font: {
                    size: 12,
                    family: "Open Sans, Arial",
                    variant: "small-caps",
                    color: "#697695"
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                font: {size:12, color: "#9da3a9"}
            }
         });
});
```

So in short, I found out that flot only draws the graph if the data is in this format (comma seperated and no curly brackets):

```
[["1375937439000",29],["1375937472000",29],["1375937506000",29],["1375937539000",29],["1375937573000",29]]
```

The question is how do I turn my data to this format in a nice way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it.. Little detail hidden in the code, as usual.

For future reference, `functionMakePair` function should be like this (notice the change of => to comma):

```
function functionMakePair($pair_1, $pair_2)
{
    return (array($pair_1, $pair_2));
}
```

This way the data format will be in the required array format.

Answer (score 0):

You actually no need to turn the data format to fit the graph plot ...

If you use D3, you could easy make the anonymous functions that customized your data format.

You can use D3, and based on svg, to draw the graph and the hover line , you could add other graph component to interact as well such as a slider bar to select sub interval to enlarge, changing labels etc.

Take this as an example to develop:
http://mpf.vis.ywng.cloudbees.net/

(you can drag the yellow bar, and click the legend; for source code, click fork me on github)

Comment: Of course I'm aware of using some other plugins but the question consisted not only of flot but also passing the data in that format for future requirements. Thanks anyways..